# Getting the error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when I run my protractor tests with cucumber framework

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, protractor

I recently started working on protractor using cucumber framework. I created my first sample test of my own and got the below error

> [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver [launcher] Error:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Function.Configuration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.js:8:11)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:148:39
>       at Function.promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:147:14
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
>       at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>       at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9) [launcher] Process exited with error code 100

I re-installed cucumber but still I get the error. Can someone help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code where the error is showing up? Your error clearly states that you are using `.length` on an undefined variable. Thanks

Comment: Hi, this is my conf file for which i am getting the above error 
exports.config = {
 chromeDriver:'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
 seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   
 framework: 'cucumber',

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['testrun.feature'],

  cucumberOpts: {
  require: ['testrun_steps.js'],
     }
}

Answer (score 3):

It might be a problem with the versions you are using.

I kind of had the same issue when using `protractor v2.5.1` and `cucumber v0.9.2`. (run `protractor --version` to check)

Try changing your `package.json` file to have `"cucumber": "~0.7.0",` and run again `npm install`.

As per Anmol's response:

`npm remove cucumber
npm install --save-dev cucumber@0.7.0`

If you are using `protractor v3.x` see here https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/frameworks#using-cucumber

Comment: +1 Awesome! Saved me tons of hours. I removed my current version with npm remove cucumber and then installed the one your mentioned with npm install cucumber@0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when upgraded my cucumber to newer version 0.9.5:

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

so, it turns out that protractor does not embed cucumber any more and I have to add one line in my package.json:

```
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^0.6.0",
```

And then update "framework" in my protractor.conf as:

```
"framework": "custom", // "cucumber"
```

And then in my protractor.conf, add:

```
frameworkPath: "node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework",
```

then run `npm install`, the `TypeError` shall disappear when you run protractor test again.